# Android L Manage Profile

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an experiment with Android Manage Profile https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicManagedProfile for Android L Platform.
Android L successfully installed on my Nexus 7 and sample application of basic manage profile successfully compiled and run on the device.

The sample app correctly send intent to start the Provisioning.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,
                    activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEFAULT_MANAGED_PROFILE_NAME,
                    "Sample Managed Profile");
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, BasicDeviceAdminReceiver.getComponentName(activity));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
        activity.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Device provisioning is not enabled. Stopping.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The provisioning activity shown and display a message that require restart to encrypt the device.
After device restarted there is a notification "Continue provisioning", when I click the notification, the provisioning activity ask to restart the device again and again.

I already tried also in emulator and got the same behaviour.

Is anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your device Encryption Status in device Settings.
**Settings->Security->Encryption.**
This issue comes when your device does not get encrypt properly. 
if it status is encrypted try clearing notification.

Comment: Yes correct, I was testing on Android L Preview and its working fine on Lollipop release.